# Save state theme on ngrx

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object, ngrx

There is a theme switcher that affects the visual appearance of the app. Naturally, it does not return anything, but only boolean values.

I have a service from which a button in the header works. Actually here it is:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ThemeService {
  public _darkTheme$$: Observable<boolean> = this.store.select(selectChanges);

  constructor(private store: Store) {}

  setTheme(theme: boolean) {
    this.store.dispatch(changeTheme({ change: theme }));
  }
}
```

next - header

```
  toggleTheme(theme: boolean): void {
    this.themeService.setTheme(theme);
  }
```

html:

```html
  <mat-slide-toggle
     [checked]="themeService._darkTheme$$ | async"
     (change)="toggleTheme($event.checked)"
  ></mat-slide-toggle>
```

In the storage itself, the data is being replaced. However, when creating a module effect, I catch a bunch of errors

actually the effect itself for the storage:

```
@Injectable()
export class ThemeEffect {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private themeService: ThemeService) {}

  // @ts-ignore
  toggleTheme$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(changeTheme),
      mergeMap((change: { change: boolean }) => {
        return this.themeService.setTheme(change.change);
      }),
      // map(
      //   (i) => this.themeService.setTheme(i.change),
      //   catchError((err) => throwError(err)),
      // ),
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: you dont need effects as effect is used to perform side effect. In your reducer just update the the theme value by listening to the action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An effect should always return an action (because these are dispatched to the store). From the looks of it `themeService.setTheme` does not return an action, but is just something that needs to be invoked.
This means you have to define the effect as a non-dispatching effect.

https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/lifecycle#non-dispatching-effects

```
@Injectable()
export class ThemeEffect {
  constructor(private actions$: Actions, private themeService: ThemeService) {}

  // @ts-ignore
  toggleTheme$ = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(changeTheme),
      mergeMap((change: { change: boolean }) => {
        return this.themeService.setTheme(change.change);
      }),
      // map(
      //   (i) => this.themeService.setTheme(i.change),
      //   catchError((err) => throwError(err)),
      // ),
    );
  // 
  }, { dispatch: false});
}
```

Side-note: Please provide the errors when you create an issue.